# 'Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Must declare the scalar variable "@tempFinalTable"' error but @tempFinalTable is declared

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

(Working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

I have a query that should, in theory, return a table containing all of the tables contained within the databases of the server to which I am connected.

However, whenever I run the query, I get the following error:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@tempFinalTable".

The query itself

```sql
DECLARE @tempTableVariable TABLE (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), DB varchar(1000))
DECLARE @tempFinalTable TABLE (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), DB varchar(1000), TABLE_LOC varchar(1000))
DECLARE @DBIndex INT = 1
DECLARE @Query varchar(1000)
DECLARE @MyDB varchar(1000)
DECLARE @RowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tempTableVariable)


INSERT INTO @tempTableVariable
    SELECT [name] 
    FROM MASTER.dbo.SYSDATABASES WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

WHILE @DBIndex < @RowCount
BEGIN 
    SET @MyDB = (SELECT DB FROM @tempTableVariable WHERE id = @DBIndex)
    SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO'+ @tempFinalTable + ' (DB, TABLE_LOC) 
                  SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, CONCAT(TABLE_CATALOG, ''.'', TABLE_SCHEMA, ''.'', TABLE_NAME) 
                  FROM ' + @MyDB + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                  ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG'
    EXEC(@QUERY)
    SET @DBIndex = @DBIndex + 1
END

SELECT *
FROM @tempFinalTable
```

Any guidance as to where I have made a mistake would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Table variables go out of scope when you call dynamic sql... use a temp table instead. And this `'INSERT INTO'+ @tempFinalTable + ' (DB, TABLE_LOC)` should be this `'INSERT INTO @tempFinalTable (DB, TABLE_LOC)` - you want the table name as part of the string. (Well this actually `'INSERT INTO #tempFinalTable (DB, TABLE_LOC)`).

Comment: As @DaleK said, your string ends up as 'INSERT INTO@tempFinalTable'.

Comment: And you try and assign `DECLARE @RowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tempTableVariable)` *before* you put anything into that table variable.

Comment: *Why* are you using `NOLOCK` against `sys.databases` of all things..? The fact you are suggests you dump it in every `FROM`... Stop doing that, it's a **terrible** idea.

Comment: The insert doesn't even need to be in the dynamic statement, you could just use `INSERT INTO ... EXEC`.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you very much!

Comment: @jmag `'INSERT INTO'+ @tempFinalTable + ...` is an attempt to combine a string with the contents of a _table variable_. That's much more fun than simply resulting in `'INSERT INTO@tempFinalTable ...'`.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names, e.g. `@MyDB`, into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is that you have a syntax error, because you are trying to use the *value* of the table variable as part of the dynamic SQL string, but only a scalar variable can be used like that.

Even if you put the table variable within the string properly, you would still run into scoping issues, because variables don't pass over to dynamic SQL.

**A much better solution** is to forgo the table variable, and instead build a `UNION ALL` query to select it straight from dynamic SQL.

Note also:

- Object names are `nvarchar(128)` you can use the alias `sysname`
- You need to quote names with `QUOTENAME`
- Don't use `dbo.sysdatabases` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, they're deprecated. Instead use `sys.databases` and `sys.tables`

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  DB = ' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ',
  TABLE_LOC = ' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ' + ''.'' + s.name + ''.'' + t.name
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.tables t
JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
'
      AS nvarchar(max)), 'UNION ALL')
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- not system DB
);

PRINT @sql; --for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I can't say whether you need `QUOTENAME` *within* the dynamic query, because I don't know what result you want, or what you intend to do with the result. If need be, you can do

```sql
  TABLE_LOC = QUOTENAME(' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ') + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
```